# Windows shell script to delete temp files and folders in windows 2003 server older than 24 hours/1 days

Tags: windows, shell, scripting, windows-server-2003, windows-shell

There has been lot of confusion to come up with exact script, which would run on my windows 2003 server.

The scripts which I have tried are below:

```
forfiles.exe /p C:\Windows\Temp /s /m *.* /d - /c "cmd /c del @file

forfiles -p "C:\Windows\Temp" -s -m *.* -d -1 -c "cmd /c del /Q @path
```

**Deletes everything rather deleting files older than 24 hourr or 1 day old**

```
@echo off
cd /d "C:\Windows\Temp"
rd /s /q "C:\Windows\Temp"
```

**No option in the task scheduler to delete the files and folders older than X hours**

Note: I am not looking for Powershell, VB or Python

Please help.

Comment: Your first line should work if you add the 1 for the date switch like you did in your second line. /d -1

Comment: @ Rene: I tried something of that sort and came up with "forfiles /p "C:\WINDOWS\Temp" /M *.*  /d -1 /c "cmd /c del  @path" carrying loads of confusion on my brain.

Comment: Do you get an error or doesn't it select the right files?

Comment: Its working as expected but I got up with some other challenge here...I created a bach file on win 2k3 box and scheduled it under the task scheduler.  
 C:\WINDOWS\Temp\AeX_{A4597EF2-B2F1-4954-A2FF-A65C393439AF}_1440.tmp
  Access is denied.
  C:\WINDOWS\Temp\KB2487367_10.0.30319\*, Are you sure (Y/N)? y

  
 when I am not logged onto the server, task scheduler doesn't do anything at all. ensured that the option running the task without logon is checked

Comment: you did specify /q in your del statement?